# Moved database from Production to development - get 403 error

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, wordpress

I exported a Wordpress mysql database from my production server to my development server because I had done some updates on production and wanted them on dev.  Now I get a 403 error and no matter what I do I can't get to the localhost/devserver.  Any ideas.  I've checked the wp-config, the httpd.conf and tried to read all the suggestions in the forums but no go. I'm running the dev on a mac (OSX 10.8.6) and the production on Windows 8.  Help!

Comment: do you get the 403 on the dev host or the production site? an HTTP 403 error indicates permission is denied to the site itself, and should have nothing to do with the DB. that said, check your connection string in the app, and confirm that that user can login to the database on the dev box. Other than that, review changes to your httpd. I would generally assume that this is a web server problem.

Comment: Frank,
The 403 occurs on my dev host (mac localhost).  The Production site (Windows 8) works fine.  The WP-Config file is set correctly for that user, I just cannot get to the login page.

Comment: are you sure your client url matches the protocol your site is set up for (http vs https)? does the user under which the web site process is running have access to the folders that the web pages are locally stored in?

Comment: Frank - Interesting development. I had a backup of the wordpress folder (wordpress.002) so I exported the mysql db from the production site, deleted the mysql db in the localhost phpmyadmin and then recreated the db there and imported the download. I updated the wp-config and the wp-options files and directed them to wordpress.002.  It ran fine except I had to redo the urls.  When I then renamed the wordpress.002 folder to wordpress and reconfigured the wp-config and wp-options I got the 403., even though it had just been working as wordpress.002.  Hmmmm  what would that be? Thank you!